# How can I bridge UInt8Array through JSI?

Tags: c++, react-native

I have an RN C++ TurboModules (JSI) setup and want to bridge `UInt8Array`. The JSI setup is ready; I want to know how to handle it on the C++ side. By default, `UInt8Array` is interpreted as a `jsi::Pointer`, and I don't know what to do with it. The `UInt8Array` is just a `string` encoded via `TextEncoder`.

Should I switch to sending this array as Base64? What are the pros and cons of each method?